# How to use keras as interface of theano?

Tags: theano, keras

for tensorflow, this post very well explain how to using keras with tensorflow

https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

But, I don't find how to use keras with theano directly.

Is it impossible using like tensorflow??

Comment: Why would you do this? The whole point of Keras is to abstract all those backends away

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation is here:  https://keras.io/backend/

Basically, edit your `$HOME/.keras/keras.json` (linux) or `%USERPROFILE%\.keras\keras.json` (windows) configuration file.

Use:

`{
        "image_data_format": "channels_last",
        "epsilon": 1e-07,
        "floatx": "float32",
        "backend": "theano"
}`

(Note the "backend" is set to "theano".)

This will of course change *all* your Keras projects to use Theano.

If you only want to change 1 project, you can set the KERAS_BACKEND environment variable, either from the command line or in code before you import keras:

`import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "theano"
import keras`

(I tested this on Windows 10 with Python 3.5 with both Theano and TensorFlow installed (remove this, and it uses TensorFlow, include it and it will use Theano)).

It's nice to include in your Python source because this dependency is then included explicitly in source control.  As the underlying ML library Keras is using is not 100% abstracted (there are lots of little differences that seep through), having the code indicate that it needs one or the other is probably a good idea.

I hope that helps,

Robert